# What's the difference between capturing and killing an enemy VIP?

Tags: xcom-2

Some missions require you to capture or kill an enemy VIP. I'm assuming capturing the VIP has better rewards than killing them, but I'm curious how they differ. Does capturing let you use them as a staff member? Grant you intel? Bonus research?

What possible benefits are there for capturing an enemy VIP versus killing them?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The mission reward for VIP capture missions is both supply and intel.

If you kill the VIP, you get the supply reward, but no intel.

If you capture the VIP by knocking them out and carrying them to the extraction zone, you will get both the intel and the supply reward. You will see them on the mission loot summary screen with their hands tied behind their back, and they do not appear very interested in joining your cause. Then you will never see them again.

Comment: Also, make sure you have at least one other guy evac AFTER you evac with the unconcious VIP. otherwise it counts the 'evac all soldiers" before it counts the VIP, so it considers him dead and you get no intel.